# Kibana time is not showing in proper format

Tags: kibana

[image]

Kibana is not showing proper timing here i have time like

```
2020-11-13T18:59:59.999Z
```

but it is appering like this in Kibana dashboard screenshot attached for further details

```
Nov 13, 2020 @ 00:00:00.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the question really is:

a) The displayed date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` vs. `MMM dd, yyyy @ HH:mm:ss.SS`

b) The time difference `18:59:59` vs. `00:00:00`

If a) is the question in Kibana you can select the displayed date format in **Stack Managament > Kibana Advanced Setting > Date format**

If b) ist the question be aware of the timezone: Elasticsearch stores all timestamps in UTC. You have to specifiy the timezone of your data while storing in Elasticsearch (e.g. Logstash). Kibana shows timestamps based on the specified (user) timezone in **Stack Managament > Kibana Advanced Setting > Timezone for date formatting**.
See also here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-timezone/29270 and here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timezone-problem-in-elasticsearch-and-logstash/180163

Comment: Note to a): After changing date format (time zone) just going back in the browser doesn't apply the new format. You need to enter your query or whatever again in a new browser tab.
@Kibana 8.11.3

Answer (score 0):

Check the date format set for the map of the field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: Your date format is working on ElasticSearch with nest but not inside kibana dashboard